How to stop run-clang-tidy from inspecting source downloaded via FetchContent?
I have read various forums and SO questions, but nothing has answered it, so I will try here.
I have the following CMake:
 if(PROJECT_IS_TOP_LEVEL)
      set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS TRUE)
      find_program(CLANG_TIDY_EXECUTABLE clang-tidy REQUIRED)
      find_program(RUN_CLANG_TIDY_EXECUTABLE run-clang-tidy REQUIRED)
      add_custom_target(run-clang-tidy
          COMMAND ${RUN_CLANG_TIDY_EXECUTABLE}
              -clang-tidy-binary ${CLANG_TIDY_EXECUTABLE}
              -p ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
) endif()

Using FetchContent to download/build other sources, run-clang-tidy is including them as well. I would like clang-tidy to not run on any code obtained via FetchContent. Some have recommended CMake 3.25's SYSTEM property, and others have recommended a -header-filter that only contains the include/src directory. None of these options worked for me. Perhaps the way the 3rd party libraries are written, these options fail to cover them?
What is a fool-proof way to execute run-clang-tidy without touching any FetchContent code?
